# Java: Query a method from a class that the method was called from

Tags: java, object, reference

I have two classes,
Map and Place

Map Class:

```
public Class Map{

private Place startplace;

public void SetStartPLace(Place p){

this.startplace=p;
}

public PLace getStartPlace(){
return this.startplace;
}
}
```

Place class:

```
public class Place{

private String placename;

public void setName(String s){
this.placename=s;
}

public String getName(){
return this.placename;
}

public boolean isStartPlace(){

}

}
```

Map has methods to set (setStartPLace(Place p)) and get (Place getStartPLace()) the start place (which is Place type object)
So I am keeping a variable of type 'Place' for start place in Map class. and sets and returns it as needed.

However in the specification given there is also a method called isStartPlace() in the Place class.
which should return true if the place is a Start place in the Map object.

Kind of confusing how should I call the Map class to get this info and compare with the place object its being called from.

Place object has a string proerty called "name" which I can use to compare the two object, I just don't know how to refer current place object to the Place object returned from Map class' getStartPlace() method.

Comment: Huh? Your question is confusing. Perhaps if you reword it to a clear, understandable question, the answer may also be clear to you. Especailly, please describe in detail what you mean by *how should I call the Map class to get this info and compare with the place object its being called from.*

Comment: Hi I have edited the question. Is it clear now? I basically need to know what should I code in isStartPlace() method in Place class.

Comment: could someone please help to up vote my question. I cannot post questions anymore. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the map knows about the start place, but the place doesn't know anything about the map containing it. So if you really must implement a method such as `isStartPlace()`, you'll have to also set a relation from place to map:

```
public class Place { 
    private Map containingMap;
    ...

    public boolean isSTartPlace() {
        return this.equals(containingMap.getStartPlace());
    }
}

public class Map{

    public void setStartPlace(Place p) {
        this.startPlace = p;
        p.setContainingMap(this);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: +1 for answer, but mainly for understanding/deciphering the question